# How do I select variables in an R whose names contain a particular string?

Tags: r

I have a large data set with thousands of columns. The column names include various unwanted characters as follows:

```
col1*
col2*
col3*[Note]
```

I would like to remove all character strings starting with `*` and with `*[Note]` from all column names to be left with clean:

col1
col2
col3
What is the most efficient way to do this for 5000+ columns?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. The example doesn't have to have 1000s of columns, just a few to get the point across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `sub` from `base R`

```
names(df1) <- sub("\\*.*", "", names(df1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(string = ., pattern = "\\*.*"), everything())
```